# How to update a component in jsf

Tags: jsf

I have a `p:accordionPanel` inside its tabs I include an xhtml `ui:composition` and inside this xhtml I have a panel :

```
<p:panel styleClass="ui-panel-liste" id="dataTablePlanningSalleAppareil">
```

So what I want to do is to update this panel after an ajax event, so I have to call it's id as following:

```
update=":#{p:component('dataTablePlanningSalleAppareil')}"
```

The problem is that I can't do this since I'll have multiple panels and it will only update the latest one.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to use a class instead of id :

```
<p:panel styleClass="ui-panel-liste" styleClass="dataTablePlanningSalleAppareil">
```

since PrimeFaces Selectors are based on jQuery. Anything we specify in `@()` will be used as a jQuery selector on the current HTML DOM tree.
Therefor, update="@(.myclass)" will work in this case :

```
update="@(.dataTablePlanningSalleAppareil)"
```

Comment: Do you also know what the problem was? Since your solution to update all panels is a bit extensive isn't it?

Comment: @Kukeltje Nope I couldn't figure out what was the problem, so I'm sticking with the current solution I've found